# img src not working for some cases

Tags: php, html, image, src

what i'm basically doing is to save some images within some directory of my localhost, the problem is when i try to show them. But here's the thing:

In my directory i have two exact images, named differently, one is named based on a unique name generated, and the other is named as it would normally be named.

For example:

Image No. 1 is called:  o9z2z2f545faf1d1.jpg

Image No. 2 is called: testImage.jpg

When i want to show them i normally do it this way

```
<img src = "<?php echo $prize['Prize']['imageUrl']; ?>">
```

If i inspect the element i get "http://localhost:8080/admin/img/prizes/o9z2z2f545faf1d1.jpg"

If i do it this way it doesnt show anything.

But if i do this

```
<img src = "../../img/prizes/testImage.jpg">
```

And then if i inspect the element it gives: "http://localhost:8080/admin/img/prizes/testImage.jpg"

I check on the folder where the images are saved, and they look fine. its when i get to call them by the unique name that fails

How can i solve this?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: can put the $prize array here , the problem was cause by absolute path

Comment: @theinarasu The $prize['Prize']['imageUrl'] gives the exact same thing as if i put the src myself... It gives -> "../../img/prizes/o9z2z2f545faf1d1.jpg"

Comment: @FrankerZ i get on the console  "http://localhost:8080/admin/img/prizes/o9z2z2f545faf1d1.jpg" Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Comment: try other image by adding <img src = "../../img/prizes/o9z2z2f545faf1d1.jpg">, There may be permission issue for testimage.jpg if you are using linux systems.

Comment: Oh god.. i realized that the path saved for the image had a space somewhere in the url... insted of being something like "../../img/prizes/imageName.jpg" it was "../../img/prizes/ imageName.jpg", taking off that space solved the issue                            Thanks a lot for your time anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Try use the base tag in the head tag or absolute path of image.

```html
<img src = "http://localhost:8080/admin/img/prizes/testImage.jpg">
```